# Two retracts $A,B$ of $S^{2}$ with different relative location

Tags: general-topology

Are there two retract  subsets  $A,B$  of $S^{2}$ with the following property:

$A,B$ are homeomorphic but two pairs $(S^{2},A)$ and  $(S^{2},B)$  are not  homeomorphic.

The same  question for  $S^{n}$

Comment: Each retract of $S^n$ equals the entire sphere once $n>0$.

Comment: @studiosus I do not think so. For example consider a hemisphere.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking about deformation retracts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will identify $S^2$ with the Riemann sphere, the 1-point compactification of the complex plane. Start with the graph $G\subset {\mathbb C}$, which is the union of the four segments connecting $0$ with the points $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$. Now let $A$ be the union of $G$ with the two small disks centered at the points $\pm 1$. Let $B$  be the union of $G$ with the two small disks centered at the points $1, i$. Then, being contractible CW subcomplexes of $S^2$, both $A, B$ are retracts of $S^2$. On the other hand, there is no homeomorphism $(S^2,A)\to (S^2,B)$. Lastly, $A$ is clearly homeomorphic to $B$.

Comment: Thank you for your  answer: Interesting Idea. May  you elaborate why the pairs are not  homeomorphic?There is  an intuitional reason indicating that two pairs you mentioned are homeomorphic:

Comment: I think that there is  a  homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ which send the  first  quadrant to the upper   half plane. sending 1 to 1  and  i to -1. Now we blow up these point to obtain discs.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: No, you cannot do it. Of course, you can send a quadrant to the upper half-plane, but try to formalize what do you mean by "blow up". The reason a homeomorphism in my example does not exist is that you cannot change the cyclic order on the link of $0$ in the graph $G$ by an ambient homeomorphism of $S^2$. (Of course, you can do it by a homeomorphism $G\to G$.) And a homeomorphism cannot send a point to a disk.